# How to force TFDMoniFlatFileClientLink file flush?

Tags: database, delphi, monitoring, firedac, delphi-10.3-rio

`TFDMoniFlatFileClientLink` opens the file handle of the trace file, then writes its info, but only flushes the file at the end of execution.
The file contents cannot be inspected until this is done.

I often want to run my program to a breakpoint and inspect the trace file from there, but it is now a lot of work to find out where that point in the trace file is.

Is there a way to force an output file flush?

Notes:
- I know I can TFDMoniRemoteClientLink as an alternative, but prefer a text file
- A workaround would be if I could insert a text into the file myself, right before the breakpoint.

Comment: You can call the Notify method of the ClientLink with some appropriate parameters.

Comment: @UweRaabe Thanks, I'll take a look at that. Luckily we have the FireDAC code because they still have not updated TFDMonitor... documentation.

Comment: Something like *dmExchangeTester.FDMoniFlatFileClientLink.Notify(ekVendor,esProgress,nil,'First ApplyUpdates()',[]);* is indeed a workaround